# WPF: binding to dependency property of a class that inherits a user control base class

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a user control in wpf named "GoogleMap.xaml/.cs" where the xaml declaration starts like this:

```
<controls:BaseUserControl x:Class="CompanyNamespace.Controls.GoogleMap"
```

the code behind:

```
 public partial class GoogleMap : BaseUserControl{

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MapCenterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MapCenter", typeof(string), typeof(GoogleMap), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnMapCenterPropertyChanged));

    public string MapCenter {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MapCenterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapCenterProperty, value); }
    } 

    private static void OnMapCenterPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
        GoogleMap control = source as GoogleMap;
        control.SetCenter(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }
...
}
```

What's the correct syntax for me to be able to address the property from GoogleMap.xaml:

```
MapCenter="{Binding Location}"
```

I can only bind to this property from GoogleMap.xaml if I place the property is in the BaseUserControl class.

**Update**
GoogleMapViewModel.cs

```
public class GoogleMapViewModel : ContainerViewModel{


    private string location;
    [XmlAttribute("location")]
    public string Location {
        get {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location))
                return appContext.DeviceGeolocation.Location();

            return ExpressionEvaluator.Evaluate(location);
        }
        set {
            if (location == value)
                return;

            location = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you are inheriting from the base class it shouldn't matter where you put the property. What does your `DataContext` look like?

Comment: I think it would be better to create a custom control and define its visual in a `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: added the vm there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind a UserControl's property in its own XAML, you could declare a Style:

```
<controls:BaseUserControl
    x:Class="CompanyNamespace.Controls.GoogleMap"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CompanyNamespace.Controls"
    ...>
    <controls:BaseUserControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:GoogleMap.MapCenter" Value="{Binding Location}" />
        </Style>
    </controls:BaseUserControl.Style>
    ...
</controls:BaseUserControl>
```

The XML namespace `local` is of course redundant if its identical to `controls`.

---

You could as well create the Binding in the UserControl's constructor like:

```
public GoogleMap()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetBinding(MapCenterProperty, new Binding("Location"));
}
```